# Is it possible to create a new measure with existing measure?

Tags: looker

I have two existing measures:

```
measure: measure_1{
    type:count
    sql:${TABLE}.example1;;
    }


measure: measure_2{
    type:count
    sql:${TABLE}.example2;;
    }
```

I am trying to divide measure one with measure two like so:

```
measure: measure_3 {
      type: number
      sql:  measure_1/measure_2;;
```

I get error, table doesnt exist. IS there anyway I can use pre-existing measures to create new measures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it right, just a syntax error, you need to wrap measures in ${} otherwise Looker thinks you're referring to a SQL field.

```
measure: measure_3 {
      type: number
      sql:  ${measure_1}/${measure_2};;
}
```

tip: take into account decimals and division by zero:

```
sql:  1.0 * ${measure_1}/NULLIF(${measure_2},0);;
```